# Eclipse CDT C++ with RDT - remote indexer not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a Remote C++ project set up in my **Eclipse Indigo** installation on my Windows PC that connects to an RDT server that I have running on a remote Solaris machine. I am able to edit files and kick off builds without issue, but it appears that my source files are not being indexed by the RDT Remote Fast Indexer.

In Eclipse Indexer preferences (**Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Indexer**) I have it set to use the RDT indexer:

[image: RDT Remote Fast Indexer is enabled]

I also have the Code Indexing service enabled (**Project > Properties > Service Configurations**):

[image: Code Indexing service is enabled]

As well as Indexing in general (**Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Indexer**):

[image: Indexer is enabled in project properties]

However, I'm unable to jump to declarations in my code.

[image: Not found in index error]

I tried rebuilding the index (right click on project **Index > Rebuild**), and the only thing that happens is that the status bar briefly shows the indexer status at 0% before disappearing.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi any luck on this issue? did it get resolved for you?

Comment: @N3Xg3N Unfortunately, no. My firm has since moved from Solaris to Linux, so this is no longer an issue since we just run Eclipse on the target host.

Comment: ok Good for you, sadly no resolution available for this anywhere on the internet.